Footer at bottom of last page only (while printing)
I have a template of certificate, it has dynamic content in header, body and footer, it looks ok if print is single page but if print is more than 1 page then footer is not showing at bottom of last page.
I tried many things like position: absolute, static, fixed, below code is closest to what I need.


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: lightcyan;
}

footer {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: PapayaWhip;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  flex: 1;
}

.h500 {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  margin: 2px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <header contentEditable>Header</header>
  <article contentEditable>
    <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div>
    <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div>
    <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div>
  </article>
  <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>
</body>

</html>




Please update footer css to position:fixed; and add padding-bottom article in according to your footer height.


body{min-height:100vh;margin:0;display:flex;flex-direction:column;position:relative;}
header{min-height:50px;background:lightcyan;}
footer{min-height:50px;background:PapayaWhip;position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;left:0;}
article{flex:1;padding-bottom:50px;}
.h500{height:90vh;border:1px solid #DDD;margin:2px; page-break-after: always;}
.h500:last-child{height:calc(100vh - 70px);}   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
 </head>
 <body>

   <header contentEditable>Header</header>

   <article contentEditable>
      <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div> 
      <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div> 
      <div class="h500">I made its height:500px to show it in 2 pages</div>   
   </article>

   <footer contentEditable>Footer</footer>

 </body>
</html>




Now it is showing footer on all pages, I want only on last page
snapshot: https://ibb.co/n0FJh6G

Okay, I have updated CSS; you can try it this way, I have assigned height in vh. You have to modify the height in CSS based on your header and footer's height.

I have placed h500 to easily simulate multiple page, in actual certificate, the content is dynamic, I can not assign height to it.
